# CMD: Fails with %1

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Recently i posted a question about what the variable is of a file which you open with a batch file, which is %1.

I used this, to let my batch file copy %1 to a specific location.
After doing this, debugging and a lot of time, and it actually worked, after debugging it more, adding some features, and some more debugging, it stopped working. This is a snippet, where it seems it goes wrong (i tried `@echo on` to get my info.)

```
if not "%1:~-8%"==".package" (
set error=yes
set errmes1=File %1 does not have a .package extension.
goto :errpkg
)
copy "%1" "C:\path_to\folder"

:errpkg
cls
echo %errmes1%
...
```

(`%1=C:\path\to\it\file_something.package`)

This is the point were it goes wrong, i guess. Because it ends up with this message. What it SHOULD do, is at `if not` checking if the file has a .package extension. then, `set error=yes`, just says what it does, `set errmes1` sets an error message. and then the `goto` just  goes to some place in the batch file where it explains what the problem is. (using `%errmes1%`)

So, that's it. Here is where it goes wrong. I am 100% sure it has a .package extension. Could anyone help me, to tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously wonder how you ever got that to work. The substring syntax only works on *environment variables* (well, and pseudo-variables such as `%cd%`). That means you can do

```
%foo:~-8%
```

but not

```
%1:~-8%
```

This wouldn't even work if you *had* an environment variable named `%1%`.

Anyway, the usual idiom to check for the extension of an argument is

```
%~x1
```

So why complicate things more than necessary?

Comment: so how would i do `%~x1` in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Tried using %~x1 to extract the extension?  Your syntax doesn't work for me.

Also, can't setting variables inside the conditional get screwy in cmd.exe?

Comment: Why should it get screwy? You're just doing variable assignment and a jump afterwards. Nothing fancy there and certainly pretty little chance to screw it up.